# How do I analyse and solve "Writing large partition" warnings in Cassandra?

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

App server keeps getting the following warning logs for few tables:

> org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.format.big.BigTableWriter .
> maybeLogLargePartitionWarning Writing large partition

What does this mean? How to analyse and resolve this issue?

Answer (score 3):

This means that you have some partitions that are bigger than a configured threshold (default is 100Mb).  This is typically an indicator of problems with the data model.  The set of actions really depends on the Cassandra version used, as for example, Cassandra 3.6 should handle big partitions better (earlier versions would just crash on big partitions), but they still can put an additional load on the Cassandra process, especially for maintenance tasks.

You need to analyze why do you have such big partitions, starting by using `(or` for older versions). Plus also analyze your schema, and how you can change it to handle such big partitions.  DataStax documentation includes the [guide](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dseplanning/docs/bestPractices.html) developed by the customer-facing team for analysis of similar problems - here is the [section about large partitions](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dseplanning/docs/dataModel.html#_large_partitions).